# Keeping channel open, waiting for another player

Tags: go, channel

I have a TCP server, and I need to keep the connection open until a another player connects. I'm creating a ticker so that I can send a message to the player so that he knows the server is waiting on another player to connect.

The problem is that the player that connects get instant disconnect because of the defer func(). How can I make it that the player waiting isn't getting instant disconnect?

```
func handleConnection(c net.Conn, msgchan chan<- string, addchan chan<- Client, rmchan chan<- Client) {
    bufc := bufio.NewReader(c)
    defer c.Close()
    client := Client{
        conn:     c,
        nickname: promptNick(c, bufc),
        ch:       make(chan string),
        game:     nil,
    }
    // Register user
    addchan <- client

    defer func() {
        msgchan <- fmt.Sprintf("User %s left the game room.\n", client.nickname)
        log.Printf("Connection from %v closed.\n", c.RemoteAddr())
        rmchan <- client
    }()
    io.WriteString(c, fmt.Sprintf("Welcome, %s!\n\n", client.nickname))
    msgchan <- fmt.Sprintf("New user %s has joined the game room.\n", client.nickname)

// Here the magic I'm trying to make work

    quit := make(chan struct{})

if len(clients) != 0 && len(clients)%2 == 0 {
    close(quit)
    var black *Client
    var white *Client

    for _, player := range clients {
        if player.game == nil && black == nil {
            black = player
        } else if player.game == nil && white == nil {
            white = player
        }

        if black != nil && white != nil {
            black.ch <- "New game started, you are matched with " + white.nickname
            white.ch <- "New game started, you are matched with " + black.nickname
            newGame(black, white)
            break
        }
    }
    go client.ReadMove(msgchan)
    client.WriteLinesFrom(client.ch)
} else {
    ticker := time.NewTicker(5 * time.Second)
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-ticker.C:
                client.ch <- "Waiting for another player to connect...\n"
            case <-quit:
                ticker.Stop()
                return
            }
        }
    }()
}
}
```

Comment: If you don't want the player to get disconnected, maybe you shouldn't close the connection.

Comment: If the player leave, I need to close the connection. That's what it needs to happen.

Comment: Don't use a defer statement to handle the clean up. Defer statements are run at the end of a function call. Which is what is happening in your case.  Your client is connecting, running really quick logic, you think that its waiting  but you spin up a go routine in both your if and else statement, which means there is nothing for your code to wait for and it goes right to the end of your function afterwards, calling the defer statement.  Go routines that aren't in forever loops or wait groups don't stop execution. So either, remove the defer, use a channel to trigger that a player has left..ect